# django static files are sometimes not serving

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

Dear Stackoverflow community. I have for a while now been struggling with my static files during development in my Django project. The problem is mainly that my stylesheets are sometimes working and sometimes not. Example - my base.html's stylesheet base_style.css is always loading, but when I add a stylesheet for the file home.html which I have loaded through the jinja template tags It sometimes works and sometimes not, the same goes for my other views.

Using python3 and Django 1.11.5

Here is my settings file (Static) =

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

Here is my template Base.html =

```
    {% load static %}

    <html>
        <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
    <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'img/favicons/manifest.json' %}">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static 'img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg' %}" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


      <title>Leaf</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mainapp/base_style.css' %}" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <body>  



    <!-- NAVBAR -->

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom text-uppercase">

    <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" width="55" height="75" alt="">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Hem<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link py-md-2" href="{% url 'list' %}">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Story</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
    </nav>
</div>


      {% block content %} 






    {% endblock content %}


    <!-- FOOTER -->



       <footer class="footer-bs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 footer-brand animated fadeInLeft">
              <h2>LEAF</h2>
                <p>Suspendisse hendrerit tellus laoreet luctus pharetra. Aliquam porttitor vitae orci nec ultricies. Curabitur vehicula, libero eget faucibus faucibus, purus erat eleifend enim, porta pellentesque ex mi ut sem.</p>
                <p>© 2017, All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 footer-nav animated fadeInUp">
              <h4>— Menu —</h4>

                <ul class="list">
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 footer-social animated fadeInDown">
              <h4>Follow Us</h4>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">RSS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>

     </footer>














    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </body>





</html>
```

Here is my home.html file =

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 


{% block content %} 

{% load static %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style_home.css' %}" type="text/css" />[enter image description here][1]





<div class="block text-center my-block">
  <h1 class="header-1">Leaf</h1>
  <h4 class="header-4">A genuinly healthy all natural energy drink</h4> 

  <img src="{% static 'img/slide-one.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" >
</div>




<!-- START CAROUSEL -->

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">


    <div class="carousel-item myCarousel active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/white-background.gif' %}" alt="First slide" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block; ">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img class="img-circle img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/Man-face-one.jpeg' %}" >
        <h3 class="review-caption">"I love how it tastes so fresh"</h3>
        <p class="name-caption">Mathias</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item myCarousel">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/white-background.gif' %}" alt="Second slide" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block; ">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img class="img-circle img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/Man-face-two.jpeg' %}" >
        <h3 class="review-caption">"This is the best ive drinken"</h3>
        <p class="name-caption">Eric</p>
      </div> 
    </div>


    <div class="carousel-item myCarousel">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/white-background.gif' %}" alt="Third slide" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block; ">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img class="img-circle img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/Woman-face-one.jpeg' %}" >
        <h3 class="review-caption">"I wish this product came out years ago!"</h3>
        <p class="name-caption">Rebecca</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="carousel-item myCarousel">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/white-background.gif' %}" alt="Fourth slide" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block; ">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img class="img-circle img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/Man-face-three.jpeg' %}" >
        <h3 class="review-caption">"I Which i could drink it all the time"</h3>
        <p class="name-caption">Jake</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="carousel-item myCarousel">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/white-background.gif' %}" alt="Fourth slide" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block; ">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img class="img-circle img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/Woman-face-two.jpeg' %}" >
        <h3 class="review-caption">"I Which i could drink it all the time"</h3>
        <p class="name-caption">Anna</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- END CAROUSEL -->




<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="{% static 'img/single-can.png' %}" alt="Leaf" class="img-fluid">
        </div>


        <div class="col">

      <div class="myText" align="center">

                <h1>Leaf</h1>
                <p>"En Genuint Hälsosam, Helt Naturlig Energidryck"</p>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Mer info</button>
     </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin-left: 110px;">
    <div class="col">
       <img src="{% static 'img/middle-section-1.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 200px; width: auto;" />
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <img src="{% static 'img/middle-section-3.png' %}" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 170px; width: auto;" />

    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <img src="{% static 'img/middle-section-2.png' %}" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 155px; width: auto;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 


















{% endblock content %}
```

[Folder Structure!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cUD5.png)

(Tried to include a picture of my folder structure on here)

I really hope anyone would be able to help me with this, this is my first post on here and I am quite new at coding.

Comment: Do you run `python manage.py collectstatic` every time you make changes to your static (css) files?

Comment: I do and sometimes it does work and sometimes it unfortunately does not. For example, in my other files all the stylesheets does not even get loaded in when i inspect my page and look at the sources (Google Chrome)

Comment: Which is the exactly value of BASE_DIR? try print this or especify the code